# get min value from php array depend on column value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, min

I am trying to get the min value of a two dimentional array where another column value is grouped.

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["cid"]=>
    int(53)
    ["cpr"]=>
    int(243)
    ["cty"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["cid"]=>
    int(55)
    ["cpr"]=>
    float(270)
    ["cty"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["cid"]=>
    int(54)
    ["cpr"]=>
    float(367.65)
    ["cty"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

I want for example to get the min of all where `cty=1` then `cty=2` ....

Comment: Which value exactly should be used to determine whether one array is smaller than another? `cpr`? `cid`? all of the values for each array?  Also, do you want to get one array (the "minimum" one) for each distinct `cty` value?

Comment: I guess OP wants the minimum `cpr` for each `cty`, the minimum `cid` for each `cty`, etc. Since no specific output format is required the *minimum array* you mention seems a fair output.

Comment: sorry, to make it clear
I want the minimum cpr from cells with same cty

Answer (score 0):

try this code tested with your input array

```
$arr = array(array(
    "cid"=>'',
    "cpr"=>'',
    "cty"=>"1"
  ),
  array(
    "cid"=>'',
    "cpr"=>'',
    "cty"=>"1"
  ),
  array(
    "cid"=>'',
    "cpr"=>367.65,
    "cty"=> "2"
  ));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr[array_search(min(array_column($arr, 'cty')),array_column($arr, 'cty'))]);
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry, to make it clear I want the minimum cpr from cells with same cty.
I need for example to get the min cpr for all records with cty=1, then with cty=2 ....

Answer (score -1):

You would use [PHP's uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    $a = intval($a['cty']);
    $b = intval($b['cty']);

    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($array, 'cmp');
echo $array[0]['cty'];
```

With `$array` being your array

Comment: thank you @InzeNL for the correction, I have steel some problem with the english

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. OP is asking for the minimum value for each field in subarrays having the same `cty` value. You're just sorting the input array and this has nothing to do with OP's question.

Comment: Ok sorry, I didn't understand the question